# Optimizing People Placement - Large Data Set

Tags: database, excel, algorithm, bigdata

I'm trying to figure out the best method / program to handle this computation to get the most people happy, ie the highest value for each person while still having all values be almost equal.

There are 24 people, 100 days and 4 people need to be selected for each day. All days must be full, ie the 24 people must be spread over 400 the slots with each person getting about 8 slots.
How can I create a program / algorithm that will allow the people to rank all 100 days in order of preference as well as the top 5 people they would prefer to be selected with.  I was thinking that each day and each of the preferred people would get some sort of point value.  Then the algorithm would run through the data set and find the combination that would yield the highest amount of people the happiest while still making everyone roughly even.

Is this easily possible using something like excel?

Thanks

Comment: It certainly seems like it would be possible with Excel, but this site is not for people to write your formulas for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Smells NP-Hard to me. Not a reduction yet pops to mind yet, though.

Comment: No, I have never heard of Solver.  I'll look into using it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on "The Assignment Problem"; this is a well studied class of problems.  Off the top of my head, the Hungarian Assignment method and the Stable Marriage/Stable Roommate method might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem as a [MILP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) using Solver as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUU95Kb7HU4) and many others like it, but I am afraid that the build-in Solver may not allow enough binary variables for it to work. Get a feeling for how the problem work on a small scale and then download a [nicer solver](http://opensolver.org/).